# "Tired" VS "being tired" in this context

Tags: grammar, participle-phrases

> **Tired from work,** he went to bed early.
>
> **Being tired from work,** he went to bed early.

The former has a **past participle phrase** while the latter has a **present participle phrase**.

But I can't make out the difference in meaning between the two sentences.

Both means:

> **She was feeling tired and that made her go to bed early.**

to me.

I'm sure that there are, of course, some difference that I can't make out.

Please help me get this.

Answer (score 1):

I feel, there could be a slight difference between the sentences.

You can understand that the first sentence "Tired from work, he went to bed early." tells you two facts: He was tired from work *and* he went to bed early.

The second sentence "Being tired from work, he went to bed early." suggests the reasoning: He was tired from work, *so* he went to bed early.

Comment: Which of these do you prefer?

Comment: I personally think, the first one is just OK, because it's simpler.